# error of making backup of a database in SQL server 2008 on win 7

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, windows-7

I would like to make a backup of a database in SQL server 2008 (remote server) to a network drive on win 7.

But, the drive cannot be visible in SQL server 2008 studio. I do not have the authorization to map it in the studio.

So, I have to back it up in local C drive.

```
 Declare  @LocalFolder varchar(100)
 SET @LocalFolder = 'C:\myPath'
 SqlCmd -E -Q "Backup Database test_database To Disk='%LocalFolder%MyDB.bak'"
```

i got error:

```
 Incorrect syntax near 'SqlCmd'.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a "**\**" between %LocalFolder%MYDB.bak

```
SqlCmd -E -Q "Backup Database test_database To Disk='%LocalFolder%\MyDB.bak'"
```